# Difference between Model and $FinalModel for classification in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Currently got this Random Forest model, just seeing how well it predicts those with diabetes positive or diabetes negative

Model is calculated using the caret workflow

when looking at variable importance i was told to use the code 
`randomForest::importance(model$finalModel)`

what is the purpose of $finalModel? what is $finalModel as compared to just the original model? should it not be just be the original model passed in as the argument instead to view variable importance?

example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(car)
library(glmnet)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)

data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2")

PimaIndiansDiabetes2 <- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)

set.seed(123)

training.samples <- PimaIndiansDiabetes2$diabetes %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)

train.data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes2[training.samples,]

test.data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes2[-training.samples,]


model_rf <- caret::train(
  diabetes ~., 
  data = train.data, 
  method = "rf", 
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10), 
  importance = TRUE)


model_rf

model_rf$bestTune

model_rf$finalModel

# variable importance here 

importance(model_rf$finalModel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-81/topics/train):

> finalModel A fit object using the best parameters

Most of the times with `train` you pass some different values for hyper-parameter estimation, to find the values that achieve the best performance (using `trainControl`).

Inside `model_rf` you'll find under `finalModel` the model built with the best parameters.

FYI `caret` also has a function for variable importance plotting: [varImp](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-81/topics/plot.varImp.train).